# Trigger wont work

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, syntax-error

I created Trigger which check the payment in ads table and supposed to update another table (customer_account) does anybody know where bug is?

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Payment_check
   after UPDATE ON Ads
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   IF NEW.Pay_done==('y'||'Y')THEN
   UPDATE customer_account SET customer_account.Plcd_ads = NEW.Ad_id
   WHERE customer_account.C_id = NEW.Customer;
   ELSE
   UPDATE customer_account SET customer_account.Pend_ads = NEW.Ad_id 
   WHERE customer_account.C_id = NEW.Customer;
   END IF;
   END;


 //////bug

 Error at line 7: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the                                                                following:

  mod  
  continue current sql execute forall merge
 pipe purge
 The symbol "" was substituted for "." to continue.

5. IF NEW.Pay_done==('y'||'Y')THEN
6. UPDATE customer_account SET customer_account.Plcd_ads = NEW.Ad_id
7. WHERE customer_account.C_id = NEW.Customer;
8. ELSE
9. UPDATE customer_account SET customer_account.Pend_ads = NEW.Ad_id
```

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql?

Answer (score 5):

Please also provide the table creation statements, so that it is easy to reproduce your error.

Here are two possible issues. Change these and update the question if this does not fix the errors.

1) NEW operator needs to be prefixed by a ":"

2) the condition to check the    pay_done flag could just be "upper(:NEW.Pay_done) = 'Y'"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Payment_check
AFTER UPDATE
   ON Ads
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF upper(:NEW.Pay_done) = 'Y' THEN
       UPDATE customer_account SET customer_account.Plcd_ads = :NEW.Ad_id
       WHERE customer_account.C_id = NEW.Customer;
       ELSE
       UPDATE customer_account SET customer_account.Pend_ads = :NEW.Ad_id 
       WHERE customer_account.C_id = :NEW.Customer;
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rajesh Chamarthi  Thank You for response your code wont work either but was helpfull to find out my  bubs. The colons where missing before NEW values and

```
     IF NEW.Pay_done==('y'||'Y')THEN
     changed for
     IF NEW.Pay_done=('y'||'Y')THEN
```

And Work!

Comment: @Alex - on the contrary this appears to be an answer, specifically a working improvement to another, allegedly non-working answer.